# Как создать функцию с таймаутом на socket-сервере?

Tags: php, рекурсия, websocket

Есть soket-сервер который работает на php (Rachet). Надо сделать отправку уведомлений по необходимости через каждые 30 секунд. Подскажите как реализовать правильнее?

```
function timeoutNotify($start, $conn,$message){
    if(time() !== $start){ 
       return timeoutNotify($start, $conn, $message);
    }else{
        $conn->send(json_encode(['type' => 'notify', 'message' => $message]));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Написал такую функцию, но она почему то не работает. Вызываю так:

```
$this->timeoutNotify(time()+5, $conn, 'Test message');
```

Comment: Функция что возвращает? И когда вы её вызываете, раз в 30сек?

Comment: "демон" останавливается

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем примере Вы ходите по краю рекурсии.

Проще сделать что то типа

```
while(true) {
    $conn->send(json_encode(['type' => 'notify', 'message' => $message]));
    sleep(30);
}
```